# How to set an expression as a watchpoint in LLDB?

Tags: debugging, lldb

Here is a program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *arr = NULL;
    arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(*arr));
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    return 0; // break is here
}
```

I want to examine the content of an `arr` on a break. Here is how I usually do it:

```
$ lldb main
(lldb) break set -l 266
(lldb) run
Process 9093 launched: '..../main' (x86_64)
Process 9093 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'main', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000555555555314 main`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fffffffe018) at main.c:266
   263      arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(*arr));
   264      arr[0] = 1;
   265      arr[1] = 2;
-> 266      return 0;
   267  } 
(lldb) x/d -c 2 arr
0x555555757260: 1
0x555555757264: 2
(lldb) p *(int(*)[2])arr
(int [2]) $9 = ([0] = 1, [1] = 2)
```

Everything is good - the content is printed as expected but the problem is I want LLDB to do it for me whenever I do stepping. So how can I set a watch point (either by means of `watch set var ...` or `watch set expr ...`) to print those values automatically on each of the `step`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a `stop-hook` here.

```
target stop-hook add -o 'p *(int(*)[2])arr'
```

If you hit return after `target stop-hook add`, you can enter multiple commands to do on every stop.  This command takes *many* options for running when you stop on certain source files, functions, in certain solibs, etc., it's pretty flexible.

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you